# In layperson's terms, what is a general affine group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, symmetric-groups

I am trying to calculate the total number of subgroups for each subgroup in $S_5$. One [subgroup in $S_5$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S5#Subgroups) is the general affine group $GA(1, 5)$.

The same [website](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/General_affine_group) provides a definition of the general affine group. For someone new to group theory, the page is not too beginner friendly. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) isn't too much better. I have tried picturing a Cayley graph, but I do not know where to begin.

What is a general affine group in simple terms?

Comment: if you know the general linear group, then it is basically linear automorphisms plus translations (transformations that shift the origin of a vector space around.) The trick is that it records what happens when you shift and then do some linear automorphism. It's basically invertible matrices but you're allowed to move the origin.

Comment: @AndresMejia Thanks for the response! I should clarify that I am currently taking group theory in high school. I am not entirely sure what the terms "general linear group" and "automorphism" refer to. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Sure. It’s best to think over the real numbers for now. The general linear group consists of matrices that have an inverse. The group operation is matrix multiplication (or composition of linear functions.) one requirement of linear functions or matrices is that they send zero to zero. Affine transformations don’t have to do this. Automorphism just means invertible. One way to get started is that they are maps that combine reflection, dilation, rotation, and translations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$GA(n,q)$ for $q$ a prime power is the matrix group consisting of matrices in $\mathbb M_{(n+1)×(n+1)}(\mathbb F_q)$ of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}A&v\\\mathbf 0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A$ is an invertible $n×n$ matrix and $v$ is of length $n$. $GA(n,F)$ for $F$ an arbitrary field is much the same, $F$ replacing $\mathbb F_q$.

$GA(1,5)$ may therefore be represented as the group of $5×4=20$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb F_5$ of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
with $a\ne0$; that it is a subgroup of $S_5$ holds only in the abstract sense. $GA(2,\mathbb R)$ is famous in SVG as the group of all (invertible) `transform` strings:
$$\text{matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)}=\begin{bmatrix}a&c&e\\b&d&f\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
When applied to a 2D point $(x,y,1)^T$, $a=b=c=d=0$ gives a translation, $e=f=0$ gives a linear transformation (rotation, reflection, shearing, etc.) and the general case performs the linear part and then the translation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If you don't mind elaborating, I've got a couple of questions. 1) Is a matrix group just a set of matrices with an operation (what is the operation, if so)? 2) Would you mind explaining what $\mathbb F_q$ and a "field" is?

Comment: @StackOverflow Matrix groups have _matrix_ multiplication as the group operation and $\mathbb F_q$ is standard notation for the finite field on $q$ elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response again! I get that a field is a set where addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division is defined and defined just like in rational and real numbers. I'm not sure what a "finite field on $q$ elements" looks like though. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking further, how did you get $5 \times 4 = 20$ matrices for $GA(1, 5)$?

Comment: @StackOverflow You can look up Wikipedia on finite fields; $20$ comes about because of $4$ nonzero choices for $a$ (to ensure invertibility) and $5$ for $b$.

Comment: For $p$ prime, $\Bbb F_p$ is just $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, the integers modulo $p$. Any other finite field is a simple algebraic extension of some $\Bbb F_p$ by an additional element that satisfies a polynomial equation, just like $\Bbb C$ is obtained from $\Bbb R$ by adjoining an element $i$ that satisfies $i^2+1=0$.

Comment: @StackOverflow It's not clear if this is what you're asking, but the $20$ comes from basic combinatorics. You have $4$ choices for $a$ and $5$ choices for $b$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).